# Загрузка данных при связи Многие ко многим

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. В базе данных есть 2 таблицы. И у них друг с другом связь многие ко многим. Пользователи и анкеты. Вот их классы:

```
class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Patronimyc { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Questionnaires> Questionnaires { get; set; }
        public Users()
        {
            Questionnaires = new List<Questionnaires>();
        }
    }
class Questionnaires
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int SubjectsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Subjects Subjects { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Questions> Questions { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
        public Questionnaires()
        {
            Users = new List<Users>();
        }
    }
```

На форме есть грида. Загружаю в неё анкеты с помощью ленивой загрузки:

```
Context db;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            db = new Context();

            db.Questionnaires.Load();
            db.Users.Load();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Questionnaires.Local.ToBindingList();
        }
```

При миграции этих таблиц создалась ещё 1. Третья таблица для связи, где айдишник юзера и айдишник анкеты. Заполнил эту таблицу само собой. Юзеров тоже подгружаю, так как мне нужно выбирать все анкеты по конкретному юзеру и наоборот, всех юзеров которые прошли конкретную анкету. Но когда смотрю в отладке в код, вижу что за анкетами юзеры не тянутся, то есть коллекция юзеров пустая. Почему так происходит? Я ведь специальноуказал что юзеров тоже нужно подтягивать. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

Comment: Будем точны в терминологии: использование метода `Load` это как раз таки не ленивая загрузка.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, очень помогли в вопросе...